# redesign chatter in lightning component

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, chatter, css, lightning-design-system

I'd like to put a chatter feed in a lightning component and put this component in a community. I already did that :

visualforce page :

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<chatter:newsfeed />
</apex:page>
```

and in the lightning component I put :

```
<iframe src="https:mysite.salesforce.com/apex/Chatter" width="100%" height="500px;" frameBorder="0"/>
```

I did get the chatter feed, designed like in salesforce classic, but I would like to apply some style to it, like the lightning design system, so the chatter feed will look like the feed in lightning experience...

Is it possible to apply the lightning design system to chatter ?

I also try this code in my component, instead of the iframe :

```
<forceChatter:feed type="groups"/>
```

but I only get that :[image]
and that is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify another feed `type` in `<forceChatter:feed type="..."/>`.

E.g. "News", "Home".
Maybe you don't have any feeds from your groups.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, I change it because I know that I have some "News". So when I lauch the app by clicking app preview in the developper console, it's working : I can see the news feed, but if I put my component in the community via the community builder, it still shows nothing... do you have any idea about that ?